# How to use xcrun to compile to AppleTV?

Tags: swift, dylib, mach-o, xcrun

I'm using `xcrun` to compile a dynamic library that I want to use in AppleTV application.

Using this command, I can compile my dylib and use in OS X:

```
➜  logger git:(master) ✗ ls
main.swift
➜  logger git:(master) ✗ xcrun swiftc -emit-library main.swift
➜  logger git:(master) ✗ ls
libmain.dylib main.swift
➜  logger git:(master) ✗ file libmain.dylib 
libmain.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

But, I can't use it in AppleTV simulator. The `dlopen` command return `nil`.

Then, I tried some parameters, like bellow, but not work correctly

```
➜  logger git:(master) ✗ xcrun swiftc -emit-library -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk appletvsimulator10.1) main.swift
<unknown>:0: warning: using sysroot for 'AppleTVSimulator' but targeting 'MacOSX'
ld: warning: URGENT: building for OSX, but linking against dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator10.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation) built for tvOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
ld: warning: URGENT: building for OSX, but linking against dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator10.1.sdk/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib) built for tvOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
ld: warning: URGENT: building for OSX, but linking against dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/AppleTVSimulator10.1.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib) built for tvOS. Note: This will be an error in the future.
```

How to compile my Swift code to dynamic library to use in AppleTV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simulator:

```
xcrun swiftc -emit-library -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk appletvsimulator10.2) main.swift
```

For physic device:

```
xcrun swiftc -emit-library -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk appletvos10.2) main.swift
```